# python lxml how to add reference of text attribute as value to list

Tags: python, lxml

I have an xml object parsed with objectify:

```
<sources>
  <source type="IP">
    <id>1000</id>
    <ip_address>100.100.1.11</ip_address>
    <netmask>255.255.255.255</netmask>
    <cidr>32</cidr>
  </source>
</sources>
```

I want to add the IP address value with a "/" and the cider as a string to a list with this code:

```
if source.get('type') == 'IP':
    source_lst.append(source.ip_address.text)+'/'+str(source.cidr)
```

I get back a list with references to the `xml` Object instead of a list of strings. When I print an object in the list with this code:

```
for x in i.sources:
    print x
```

I get nothing back. But with the `etree.tostring`:

```
  for x in i.sources:
        print etree.tostring(x)
```

It shows me the full XML object:

```
<source xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" type="IP"><id>989</id><ip_address>100.100.1.10</ip_address><netmask>255.255.255.255</netmask><cidr>32</cidr></source>
```

Why does my code add the full XML object if i just add the text attribute in my code as string?

With the comment I got I decided to change the code, but I does not provide the result I am expecting.

```
    sources = access_request.sources.findall('source')
    for source in sources:
        if source.get('type') == 'IP':
            ip_address = source.ip_address.text
            cidr = source.cidr.text
            my_string = ip_address+'/'+cidr
            print my_string
            source_lst.append(my_string)
```

With the "print mystring" I get this line:

```
100.100.1.10/32
```

But when i try to print the item from the list I still get the xml objects instead of the string.

I found the problem. It was not with this part of the code. 
Question can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to why your code didn't work, because it was not a complete example. But I believe that you wanted to construct a list of `ipaddr/cidr` strings from the sample XML.  Here is some `lxml` code to scan the source records and append them to a list as `ipadd/cidr` strings:

**Python Code:**

```
from lxml import etree

source_lst = []
sources = etree.fromstring(my_xml)
for source in sources.findall("source[@type='IP']"):
    ip_address = source.findtext('ip_address')
    cidr = source.findtext('cidr')
    source_lst.append(ip_address + '/' + cidr)

print(source_lst)
```

**Example data:**

```
my_xml = """
    <sources>
      <source type="IP">
        <id>1000</id>
        <ip_address>100.100.1.11</ip_address>
        <netmask>255.255.255.255</netmask>
        <cidr>32</cidr>
      </source>
      <source type="IPx">
        <id>1000</id>
        <ip_address>100.100.1.12</ip_address>
        <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
        <cidr>24</cidr>
      </source>
      <source type="IP">
        <id>1000</id>
        <ip_address>100.100.1.13</ip_address>
        <netmask>255.255.255.0</netmask>
        <cidr>24</cidr>
      </source>
    </sources>
"""
```

**Prints:**

```
['100.100.1.11/32', '100.100.1.13/24']
```